# Call a methods from different files in C

Tags: c

So, in class, we're going over functions but I'm a bit lost as to how you might go about calling multiple functions in multiple files. Like, say in a project I have three files in addition to the header, one that takes variables in from a text file, one that runs various calculations from those variables and finally a main that holds everything together.

header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <ctype.h>
```

main.c

```
#include "header.h"

void main(){
FILE *f, *o;
int a, b, c, sum;

while(getInt() != EOF){
    fprintf(calc()); 
}
```

input.c:

```
int getInt(FILE *f, int a, int b, int c){
    fscanf(f, "%i %i %i", a, b, c);
}
```

calc.c:

```
int Calc(){
    sum = a+b+C;
}
```

The part I'm mainly having trouble with is the bit with calc() in the main file. Is that the proper way to call and print that method to a file? Or is there a better way? Also, would I need to import getInt into calc or is what I have fine since main is supposed to take both functions and make them work? Thanks for any help of insight anyone might be able to give me.

Comment: s/`Calc`/`calc` and return a value from that function.

Comment: @user0042 That's the most obscure way of saying a simple thing I've ever seen.

Comment: @CareyGregory The substitution syntax (s/<x>/<y>) is pretty common.

Comment: also, `getInt`must return a value too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>

int getInt(FILE *f, int *a, int *b, int *c);
int calc(int a, int b, int c);

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "header.h"

int main(void){
    FILE *f, *o;
    int a, b, c;/* sum; */

    f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    o = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if(!f || !o){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(getInt(f, &a, &b, &c) != EOF){
        fprintf(o, "%d\n", calc(a,b,c)); 
    }
    fclose(o); fclose(f);
}
```

input.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int getInt(FILE *f, int *a, int *b, int *c){
    return fscanf(f, "%i %i %i", a, b, c);
}
```

calc.c:

```
int calc(int a, int b, int c){
    return a + b + c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main.c doesn't know about your functions, so it won't compile. You could create an input.h that has a prototype for getInt, and have both main.c and input.c do #include "input.h"

Do the same for that other function, and report back if that works.